# how to get json file in wordpress template in wordpress

Tags: themes, json, wp-filesystem

I am trying to get data from JSON file in Wordpress template using `file_get_contents` But can not get the file

```
$data = file_get_contents("../assets/data2.json");
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
```

Facing this error while `var_dump` `$data`

> object(WP_Error)#825 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "A valid URL was not provided." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

My `data2.json` file is in the assets folder and trying from templates folder in theme folder in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents() is usually blocked to fetching content from URLs for safety reasons. You should provide a local server path. In alternative use [wp_remote_get()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get)

Comment: I already use `wp_remote_get()` but can't fix my problem.

Comment: you have to specify a full url like https://example.com/your-api